# Forgot to call ImGui::NewFrame()?

Tags: c++, sfml, imgui

I'm trying to make a project using the SFML and imgui-SFML. I'm new to imgui and not sure where exactly the problem is.
From what I've gathered, the imgui::render has to happen in the same timestep as the imgui::update, which is limiting and suboptimal in the context of SFML and handling Delta time correctly.

Here's some minimal example of my problem:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "ImGui.h"
#include "ImGui-SFML.h"


void update(sf::Time dt, sf::RenderWindow& window);
void processEvents(sf::RenderWindow& window);
void render(sf::RenderWindow& window);

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window;
    window.create(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "window");
    ImGui::SFML::Init(window);


    sf::Clock clock;
    sf::Time timeSinceLastUpdate = sf::Time::Zero;
    sf::Time mTimePerFrame = sf::seconds(1.f / 60.f);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Time elapsedTime = clock.restart();
        timeSinceLastUpdate += elapsedTime;
        while (timeSinceLastUpdate > mTimePerFrame)
        {
            timeSinceLastUpdate -= mTimePerFrame;
            processEvents(window);
            update(mTimePerFrame, window);
        }
        render(window);
    }
    return 0;
}

void update(sf::Time dt, sf::RenderWindow& window)
{
    ImGui::SFML::Update(window, dt);
    ImGui::Begin("Hello!", NULL);
    ImGui::Button("click me", ImVec2(32, 32));
    ImGui::End();
}

void processEvents(sf::RenderWindow& window)
{
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        ImGui::SFML::ProcessEvent(event);
    }
}

void render(sf::RenderWindow& window)
{
    window.clear();
    ImGui::SFML::Render();
    window.display();
}
```

If I remove the second while loop ( while (timeSinceLastUpdate > mTimePerFrame) ), everything works correctly, but that makes my game framerate dependent, which I obviously want to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error about new frame is triggered by [this assert](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/blob/3733b5064e1820dc8517fedba2b34bfbdef569ab/imgui.cpp#L5053) because `update` and thus `ImGui::SFML::Update` (which calls `ImGui::NewFrame`) isn't called before the first `render` call (which eventually calls `ImGui::EndFrame` linked above). Even though you have a mechanism for calling `update` with fixed time steps, the outer loop doesn't actually have any frame limiting mechanism, so what happens (or, rather, would happen if not for the assert failure) is that, on most iterations of the outer loop, inner loop isn't entered (`timeSinceLastUpdate` hasn't accumulated yet), but `render` gets called.

An easy way to fix this is to assure that `render` gets called only when there was an update of the game state (i.e. inner loop had at least one iteration) on the current outer loop iteration. We can do this by transforming the inner loop from `while` to `if-do-while` and moving `render(window);` inside `if`. Not only this solves the `ImGui::NewFrame` problem (since now by the time `render` executes it has already been called), but saves from unneccessary rendering/drawing non-updated game state.

But, now game (outer) loop just keeps iterating and unnecessarily holding its thread busy while checking time every few microseconds (if not more often) before `timeSinceLastUpdate` eventually surpasses your fixed time threshold. Instead, we can put our thread to sleep for roughly the time needed before we can enter the `if`, which can be done e.g. in `else` branch:

```
while (window.isOpen())
{
    sf::Time elapsedTime = clock.restart();
    timeSinceLastUpdate += elapsedTime;
    if (timeSinceLastUpdate > mTimePerFrame)
    {
        do
        {
            timeSinceLastUpdate -= mTimePerFrame;
            processEvents(window);
            update(mTimePerFrame, window);
        } while (timeSinceLastUpdate > mTimePerFrame);
        render(window);
    }
    else
    {
        sf::sleep(mTimePerFrame - timeSinceLastUpdate /* - clock.getElapsedTime() which is negligible here */);
    }
}
```

Note that in SFML frame limiting is often done not by `sf::sleep`, but by `sf::Window::setVerticalSyncEnabled` (VSync implemented on GPU driver level) or `sf::Window::setFramerateLimit` (which uses `sf::sleep` and `sf::Window`'s own internal clock), where the latter is particilarly similar to what we did. But both of these functions block inside `sf::Window::display` (which we call inside `render`) and are not exact (especially the latter), so, if we used them here, we could sometimes still wake up in the outer loop too early and spend a bit of time 'attacking' the `if`, to prevent which we would still have to `sf::sleep` inside `else` branch.

Also we have to call `ImGui::EndFrame` at the end of `update` so that if several iterations of the inner loop are executed we don't end up calling `ImGui::StartFrame` consequtively without `ImGui::EndFrame` in between (that would trigger [another assert](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/blob/3733b5064e1820dc8517fedba2b34bfbdef569ab/imgui.cpp#L9420)):

```
void update(sf::Time dt, sf::RenderWindow& window)
{
    // ...
    ImGui::EndFrame();
}
```

Note that now we frequently call `ImGui::EndFrame` two times in a row (the `update` in the last iteration of inner loop and subsequent `render`), but this isn't a problem since due to [this check](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/blob/3733b5064e1820dc8517fedba2b34bfbdef569ab/imgui.cpp#L5051) subsequent `ImGui::EndFrame` calls have no effect until new frame is started.